# Is there a way to play the Battle Maison with friends over online?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to defeat the Battle Maison with a friend over online, but I can not find a way to do it. Is there a way I can do it over Wi-Fi/Internet (My friend said you can only do it through local, but he is not 100% sure).

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer, because I'm not 100% sure either, but whenever @frank and I tried to Battle Mansion together, it insisted on an IR connection (point the infrared ports at each other for 30 seconds or so) before proceeding.

Comment: I agree with Trent on this one. Battle Maison can only be played multi battle style through a local IR connection.

Comment: I think that is correct @TrentHawkins, so you can post it in an answer. If I find anything on it for non-IR, I will post an answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can determine, this is not a thing that is possible. In order to set up a multiplayer Battle Maison, the game requires that you and your partner establish a infrared connection.

Presumably this is to ensure both persons are in the same room and can communicate, because the infrared connection is only used for the initial setup. As after the setup, the 3DS units are no longer required to be pointing at each other.